# How do I customize Context Help in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

Is there some easy way to write Context Help in LabVIEW such that it's more enjoyable? 
*(EDIT: Not in original question, but I believe synonyms of "more enjoyable" could be richer, prettier, more unique, etc.)*

I would like to include more information such as pictures, charts, or even text with different types of fonts but I did not find a useful manual on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for more than something like this? I believe this is as rich of a Context Help that you can achieve for your SubVIs.

[image]

You may want to look into [Creating and Editing VI Descriptions](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361E-01/lvhowto/creatingediting_vi_desc/) so that you're at least including a useful Description in your SubVIs. Quoting an answer on [this NI forum thread](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/How-to-document-a-labview-project/td-p/29231), I list a few things that should be included in your SubVIs:

> 1. General: (VI name, Version #, Date coded, Author).
> 2. Description: (paragraph that summarizes its overall functionality).
> 3. Specifics: (detailed sub paragraphs that specify unique or complex code).
> 4. Misc: (data type input/outputs, unique conditions for the vi to work, limitations, etc.).

Lastly, I point to this old but useful [LabVIEW Development Guidelines](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/321393c.pdf), also referenced in the above thread. See Chapter 5 - Creating Documentation.

Comment: thanks for answer. I would like to include some math - sum character, indexes, ...

Comment: @user1281071 It's an interesting thought but I'm pretty certain the present versions of LabVIEW are not designed for this. You're limited to the SubVI Name, Icon, Wiring Names and Description. I don't have a version of LabVIEW at the moment so I'm not sure whether Detailed help is customizable for SubVIs as well.

Answer (score 0):

The context help in LabVIEW is indeed limited.

I believe [you already asked the question on the NI LabVIEW forum](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Writing-context-help-in-labview/td-p/1975683) and received the same answer.

From the NI Web site: [Formatting Text in the Context Help Window](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/bold_context_help_text/)